# Why doesn't my ImageView display inside of a fragment but does in an activity?

Tags: bitmap, imageview

I'm trying to set a simple ImageView from a drawable inside a TabFragment. Here is the code I've created.  I've made it as simple as I can, by loading from a drawable bitmap.  The ImageView in the fragment never gets set to the resource bitmap but the ImageView in the activity does.

```
public class MondayTabFragment extends Fragment
{
  public MondayTabFragment()
  {

  }

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_monday_tab, container, false);
    ImageView image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.myTabView);

    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.valve1);
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_monday_tab, container, false);
  }
}
```

Here is the associated XML file.

```html
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  tools:context="com.terryneckar.sprinkon.MondayTabFragment">    
  <ImageView
    android:layout_width="144dp"
    android:layout_height="144dp"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/alert_light_frame"
    android:id="@+id/myView"
    android:layout_marginStart="80dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is the code inside the activity and the corresponding XML file.

```
public class Schedule extends AppCompatActivity
{ 
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_schedule);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Monday"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tuesday"));

    final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    final PagerAdapter adapter = new TabPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener()
     {
       @Override
       public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab)
       {
         viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
       }
       @Override
       public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab)
       {
       }
       @Override
       public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab)
       {
       }
     });

    View view = this.findViewById(R.id.myTestView);
    ImageView image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.myTestView);
    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.valve1);
  }
}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:id="@+id/content_schedule"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
  android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
  android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
  android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
  app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
  tools:context="com.terryneckar.sprinkon.Schedule"
  tools:showIn="@layout/activity_schedule">

  <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>

  <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tab_layout" android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>
  <ImageView
    android:layout_width="194dp"
    android:layout_height="144dp"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/alert_light_frame"
    android:id="@+id/myTestView"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tab_layout"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:contentDescription="test View"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I compared the parameters in the value of "image" from the AppCompatActivity and TabFragment and found that they were the same, except for values that you would expect to be different.  What I'm seeing is that setting the imageView to a bitmap appears to be working except that it is not visible.  One of the parameters of the imageView is mVisible and it is true in both circumstances.  Does anyone have any clues?

Comment: I updated to Android Studio 2.3 and buildToolsVersion "25.0.2" and there was no change.  I also created a separate clean program with only two tabfragments and it reacts the same way.  Apparently, from what I can tell so far, an ImageView will not work inside of a tabfragment, unless I'm totally missing something.

Answer (score 0):

In the "onCreateView" of "MondayTabFragment" class, I should have returned "**view**" instead of "**inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_monday_tab, container, false)**" because it was already inflated.